# Mongodb how to update element only if it equals a string x?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I am trying to do something like this:

```
DB.update({_id}, {$set: {name: 'Bar'}}); // Set name to Bar only if name is Foo
```

But I only want to update the name to 'Bar', given that the current name is 'Foo'. How to do this?

Comment: refer this link  : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
db.collection.update({name:"Foo"}, {$set: {name: "Bar"}}, {multi:true})
```